# Find the closed form for the following expression

Tags: combinatorics

let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence that satisfies the following

$$a_n = 3a_{n-1}+6a_{n-2}-28a_{n-3}+24a_{n-4}$$

for all integers $n\ge4$ and $a_0=4, a_1=0,a_2=42,a_3=34$

find a closed form for $a_n, n\ge0$

First I can identify the characteristic polynomial as:

$$x^4=3x^3+6x^2-28x+24$$

from the examples I've seen I'm pretty sure I need to factor this so I can use this theorem

$$a_n=P_1(n)B_1^n+...+Pj(n)B_j^n$$
where $B_i$ is a root with multiplicity $m_i$, and $P_i(n)$ is a polynomial with degree less than $m_i$

but the characteristic polynomial does not factor into nice roots like the examples, so I'm unsure of how to proceed.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your characteristic polynomial is not correct.  If you assume $a_n=br^n$ and substitute in to the recurrence, one of your exponents is wrong and you lost the left hand side.

Comment: Oops I meant that to be an $x^3$

Comment: That is one.  The second is that the left side of the recurrence contributes to the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: You still missed the left hand side. You want to find the roots of $x^4=3x^3+6x^2-28x+24$.

Comment: Is the $x^4$ significant? It's been left out in the examples I'm looking at.

Comment: Oh wait I see you can move it over the the right side then factor to get $-(x-2)^3(x+3)$. I think I can proceed from here. I didn't look at the examples carefully enough. Thanks for your help!